# Issue Regarding Join Statements (Or Other Efficient Method) in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

It took a while to come up with a title as I wasn't sure what to title it. Basically my problem deals with `SQL queries` and coming up with an efficient method to go about what I am trying to do.

To give it in an example, say we have two tables:

```
Table 1 (Articles): ID | ArticleName | AuthorID
Table 2 (Users):    ID | AuthorName
```

What I am attempting to do is pull, say the last 5 articles. From here, with each article it pulls it has a while loop to query the second table to pull `AuthorName where ID=AuthorID`.

In essence, we have one query for the 5 articles and then another **five** queries to get the author names. This is further compounded on pages with 10-20 or more articles, where there's an extra 10-20+ queries.

Is there a more efficient method to join these statements together and have it pull the AuthorName for *each* article it pulls?

The reason for using AuthorID in table 1 is so that if usernames are changed, it doesn't break anything. Along with this, it (as far as I understand) cuts down a lot on the database storage.

I'm still somewhat new to SQL though so any ideas on how to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance, and if there are any questions please don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: The DBA in me is already asking "Are you sure there's only one author per paper?"

Comment: @tadman You do bring up an interesting thing to think about (I'm still learning SQL so... this is more of a hypothetical situation than anything). If there were more authors they could just be stored in an 'author, author, author' format. From here, though, it would take a "while" loop to iterate through each author after the array has been broken down (using , as the delimiter) right? Or would there be an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `Articles` INNER JOIN `Users` ON `Articles`.`AuthorID`=`Users`.`ID`
```

Comment: The above query will select all the articles (and the authors) whereas the OP wanted only the last five articles. The use of the word 'last' by the OP indicates a certain lack of knowledge regarding SQL - what are the 'last five'? The last five added? The last five by alphabetical order of article subject?

Comment: A `LEFT JOIN` might be safer because it would still retrieve articles with invalid authors.

Comment: @No'amNewman I'd assume that he'd want the last five in the table, which is normally sorted by the primary key; so, with that, I could add `ORDER BY \`Articles\`.\`ID\` DESC LIMIT 5` to the end of the query and get what I'd think he wants.

Comment: If you join, you'd need `ORDER BY Articles.ID` to make it work. `ID` will be an ambiguous column name.

Comment: @tadman I realized that after posting the comment and edited it to fix that, thanks :D

Comment: Very nice! One more question then. That worked and there are actually multiple fields in the Users table. How can I pull just the username when I am using the Inner Join?

Comment: @Bryan `SELECT \`Articles\`.*, \`Users\`.\`AuthorName\` ...`, I think

Comment: Using `SELECT *` is a very lazy way of making a query. You should be asking for the specific columns you care about. It's pronounced "Select, like, whatever man, from..."

Comment: I got it now! And this also helped to learn how the joins actually work. I'm still learning and this was *extremely* beneficial. I was able to adopt this as needed. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: @tadman that made me chuckle, and you're right; I guess ActiveRecord has softend my SQL

Comment: @drderp that would work. Question though: I need all information but the article's ID. Should I still go ahead and use * or just list out the columns needed? There are about 6 columns total. And on that note, if you have something with columns, say "1, 2, 3, 4" is it better to do select 1, 2, 3, 4 from (...) or to select *?

Comment: @Bryan If you're going to use all of the data, and you know it, you should use `*`.  Otherwise, try to remove fields from the select that you're not going to use.

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to do this. You can either do a one-shot query that `JOIN`s in the additional authors table and presents a complete result set, or you can do a two pass where you fetch all the authors in a subsequent call using `SELECT ... FROM Authors WHERE ID IN (...)` using the distinct identifiers from the first query.

For small lists and small tables the `JOIN` method will almost always be more convenient. For large lists the two-pass approach seems "dumber" but often out-performs doing the join in the database. For instance, if the number of articles is very large and the number of authors is small then the `JOIN` adds significant amounts of work to the large query that could be eliminated by making a small secondary query after the fact.

For this case, with less than one million records and small fetch sizes, go with `JOIN`.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're basically saying to go with joins for this (I'm learning how they work now!) if it's a smaller site, but if it's larger to go with my current approach (to do one pass to pull in, for example, articles, and then a while loop to find the corresponding information for each one pulled)?

Comment: The two-pass approach is also called "eager loading" in some frameworks. If you ever find a join is taking stupidly long, keep that in your toolbox to try.

Comment: Will definitely do. Thanks, :).